# ¿Cómo guardar datos en una sesión?

Tags: php, session, php5, sesiones

¿Cómo guardar datos en una sesión y cuándo se recargue la página muestre los actuales y los anteriores?

Éste es el código:

```
class Arreglo {

    private $miArreglo = array();

    function agregar($dato)
    {                                                  
        array_push($this->miArreglo, $dato);
    }

    function guardarSesion()
    {            
        if(!isset($_SESSION['MiArreglo']))
        {
            session_start(); 
            $_SESSION['MiArreglo'] = $this->miArreglo;
        }
    }

    function leerSesion()
    {            
        session_start();
        return $_SESSION['MiArreglo'];
    }
}
```

Y ésta es la página donde mando a llamar:

```
require "GuardarSesion.php";
$arreglo = new Arreglo();
$arreglo -> agregar(67);
$arreglo -> guardarSesion();
var_dump($arreglo -> leerSesion());
```

Comment: Hola Estefania, por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el código como texto, no como una foto de tu pantalla.

Answer (score 0):

Al momento de asignar en la variable `$_SESSION['miArreglo']` Guardaste fue un array, para leerlo debes tratarlo como tal

```
echo $_SESSION['miArreglo'][0];
echo $_SESSION['miArreglo'][1];
```

Comment: Aunque debo Mostarlo desde otra página de sesión y traerme lo que guardé sn sesión y como mostrar después de haber recargado la página?

Comment: siempre debes asegurar de que la `session` este iniciada, al momento de recargar la pagina no tendras problema, asi desde otro archivo php